# joining two tables with date range

Tags: vb.net

i have 2 tables.

```
Table A                      Table B  
 DATE         QTYA             DATE         QTYB  
--------------------         --------------------  
 Jan1          5                Jan1          6  
--------------------         --------------------  
 Jan2          10               Jan3          10
```

I want an output like this. im using OLEDB.please help.TIA

```
Out Put
 DATE         QTYA             QTYB
 Jan1           5               6
 Jan2           10
 Jan3                           10
```

Comment: `I want....` is not a question and this site requires you show some effort to fix your own problem(s).  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: sorry this is my first time here

Comment: I am very well aware.  Thats why I suggest you carefully read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: thank you very much.i will..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination of a union and a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN source = 'A' THEN QTY END) AS QTYA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN source = 'B' THEN QTY END) AS QTYB
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE, QTYA AS QTY, 'A' AS source
    FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE, QTYB, 'B'
    FROM TableB
) t
GROUP BY DATE;
```

This assumes that the dates you expect in your output appear in the A and/or B table.  If you expect a certain coverage of dates which your data lacks, then you may have to create and join with a calendar table.

Comment: can i ask another question ?how to create a calendar table? :)

Comment: Just create a new table which contains all the dates you want to appear in your output.  If, for example, neither table had January 4, but you still wanted to report that day, then you could left join a calendar table to my query, and report on January 4.